# Titanium Android - showCamera. Image rotation working on 3.0.0.GA, not working on 3.0.0.2 or later

Tags: android, coffeescript, titanium

I'm trying to display an image in a Titanium webView, that I took with the showCamera function.

The image isn't rotated properly. If I take a photo in portrait mode, it always appears in landscape mode.

This only happens for version 3.0.2 and higher. As I'm developing a cross plattform App, it is very undesirable to work with 2 different Titanium versions. On iOs everything is working out fine.

Titanium.Media.showCamera success callback, coffeescript

```
imageFile = event.media     

imageAsTaken = Ti.UI.createImageView
  image : imageFile,
  autorotate : true

if Ti.Platform.osname isnt 'android'
  imageFile = imageAsTaken.toImage()
else 
  imageFile = imageAsTaken.toBlob()

image.write( imageFile.imageAsResized(width,height) )
```

The image is later displayed in an img tag in a Titanium.UI.WebView.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use imageAsTaken.toImage().media for android to get blob object. and if still get problem then try to first add that imageview in window then try to get blob image. Its for android only.